# SpringMVC - Change view when accessed by Mobile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mobile-website

I was wondering if someone has already solved this. I have a **SpringMVC** app and we are adding support to **WebKit** type mobiles (iPhone and Android basically) so I was wondering someone has found an elegant way of defining specific views depending on the client that sent the request.

I know that a simple *if* in a Controller implementation can do the trick, but I'm looking for something more flexible/elegant (a specific ViewResolver implementation, or an interceptor maybe).

Help will be greatly appreciated... as always =)

---

This is a pretty old question. What you need to do is use [Spring-Mobile](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/) to achieve this in a standard elegant manner

Comment: I think this is a good idea. I created [a JIRA issue](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-7518) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a more specific answer. There is a problem with the solution that Bozho proposed. the fact that the **ViewResolvers** no longer have access to the **HttpServletRequest**. There is a [way to access the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192883/spring-accessing-httpservletrequest-in-a-custom-viewresolver) but its kind of dirty IMHO.

So that said, this is a very elegant and easy to implement [solution](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=19073). Basicly it involves a custom ViewResolver (as Bozho proposed) but it adds an handlerInterceptor that adds the User-Agent to the model so you no longer have to add it manually.

Answer (score 9):

Update: look at [spring-mobile](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/)

Original answer:

It would be pretty simple to create a custom `ViewResolver` that resolves views based on the `User-Agent` header.

- [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/) is a list of mobile user agents (page removed from wikipedia). Check the header against it, and resolve a mobile view.
- if the user-agent is not a mobile, then return `null`, thus letting other resolvers resolve a view.
- make sure your resolvers are defined (in the spring xml) in the proper order, so that the mobile resolver is consulted first.

Comment: Ok, just one concern about this... Do I still have access to the HTTP request on the ViewResolver, If so, how do I access it without specifically passing it on each and every Controller?

Comment: You can get the request from `RequestAtrributesHolder` (cast the attributes to `ServletRequestAttributes`)

Comment: Yep, but that can only be done at Controller level, ViewResolver no longer get the HTTPServletRequest unless you pass it in the model, which is something that may not be desirable.

Comment: @Chepech so you say there is nothing in `RequestAttributeHolder` in the ViewResolver? That's surprising.

Comment: it's not :) The RequestAttributeHolder is a perfectly valid class

Answer (score 2):

Like @Bohzo and yourself already said spring-mobile is the way to go.

As of version 1.1 you can use the [LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/current/api/org/springframework/mobile/device/view/LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver.html) to configure the type of behavior you're describing.

#### Device Aware View Management

http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/current/reference/html/device.html#device-aware-view-management

> Spring Mobile includes AbstractDeviceDelegatingViewResolver, an abstract ViewResolver wrapper that delegates to another view resolver implementation, allowing for resolution of device specific view names without the need for a dedicated mapping to be defined for each view. A lightweight implementation is provided, which supports adjusting view names based on whether the calling device is normal, mobile, or tablet based.
>
> Within your application, you can then create alternate views for normal, mobile or tablet devices, and given the proper configuration, Spring Mobile will adjust the view name to resolve to the correct one. This happens internally, without the need to add conditional logic through your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

> To access current Request inside ViewResolvers.

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
```